# Question erased: Logging vs Tracing

Tags: discussion, moderation

I posted a question. It got down voted and then erased entirely. I can't find that question, can't see any comments or any details about it.

What's the matter?

Comment: when did you wrote the question and what was the title?

Comment: Title was **Logging vs Tracing**. I posted it around 1/2 hr ago.

Answer (score 5):

You can't see deleted questions (unless you have a link to them and you have the power to see deleted questions) but without link, its gone.

But most likely, it is deleted because it was bad quality or a duplicate.

Here is a link: [logging vs tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369428/logging-vs-tracing)

**Update**

The question was deleted because it was too vague. Besides it was very similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172372/tracing-versus-logging-and-how-does-log4net-fit-in)

**Lessons to be learned**

1. Put more effort into your question.
2. Monitor the question frequently (specially the first hour) so you can react to comments quickly.
3. Search before asking.

Comment: but how'll i know not to repeat same mistake again if i can't see the comments and reasoning behind deletion.

Comment: @Azodious, I added the link.

Comment: it results into HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: @Azodious, ok then you are not able to view your own deleted question.

Comment: yup!!, don't know wats the issue :-(

Comment: and thanks for providing similar question. i got my answer from that.

Comment: See also : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted about the "own deleted question"